# TWR-VF65GS10, how to programm?

Tags: stm32, embedded, nxp

We have a task to design IEEE 61850 compatible board. So we considered several options for MCU for the board: stm32f7xx series or something more powerful like NXP MVF6xx series or Sitara AM3358 series. The question is how to design software for these platforms, if for the stm32f7xx it is quite clear for me (we can use either HAL/StdPeriph libraries and FreeRTOS) then for more powerful MCUs it is unclear because they all appear to run under embedded Linux. So as far as I understand if we for example choose NXP TWR-VF65GS10 platform as reference design we are bound to use embedded Linux and systems like buildroot/Yocto project to create our own embedded Linux Image and there is no way to use such platforms without embedded OS? Also which is the best option for fast proccessing of TCP/UDP streams - stm32f7xx with LwTCP/IP (without OS) or more powerful platforms with embedded Linux? Thanks)

Comment: `there is no way to use such platforms without embedded OS` .... embedded OS is just a program in non volatile memory that executes at powerup .... even a blink program on an Arduino is "embedded OS" .... it is what makes it do what you want it to do

Comment: So as far as I understood more powerful platforms are designed to be used with embedded OS and there is no way to use them otherwise. But what are some other tools exept for buidroot (for NXP TWR-VF65GS10) that  I can use to optimize/customise my OS image?

Comment: If you know nothing about low-level programming of a particular platform then using an existing OS on that platform is indeed your only choice.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for the STM32F7xx or Sitara, but you do not need to use embedded Linux for a VF65 Vybrid board.
I've been working with a Vybrid based device for about 3 years and I was responsible for porting the existing firmware from a Kinetis K70 to the Vybrid.
The TWR demo board you're looking at has the dual core Vybrid with both A5 and M4 cores in the chip, and it's not clear from your question if you're intending to use one or both of them.
In our application I ignored the M4 because in our production device we would be manufacturing with the A5- only version of the chip.
Our firmware uses a very lightweight OS (CTL from Rowley Crossworks) and we've written all of our own low-level driver code, and although an OS of any sort is not required I think it would be difficult to take advantage of a chip like the Vybrid without one.
The biggest learning curve for me when transitioning from a smaller micro to the Vybrid was the fact that it has no on-board Flash memory, so all of your code lives in external Flash (ours has external QuadSPI, but there are many different options).
We also have 256MB of external DDR SDRAM and at power up all of the code is copied over from the QuadSPI flash to the external RAM and executed from there (we're using most of the internal SRAM for a framebuffer for our display).
If you're already familiar with something like FreeRTOS and the HAL libraries you shouldn't have too much trouble implementing them on a Vybrid.